# Reactstrap Form Input innerRef coming back null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

Trying to send input data to console.log but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. I'd like to be able to log into console email and password from auth.

Here is my constructor and onChange:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

Here is my onSubmit:

```
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    console.log(userData);
  }
```

Here is my Input from Form:

```
<Input
  name="email"
  type="email"
  onChange={this.onChange}
  innerRef={this.state.email}
  error={errors.email}
/>
```

Not getting any errors, just email and password are coming back as null.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `onChange` function to this :

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

I think this have to solve your problem

Comment: Can't upvote you but thank you, this solved it. I just wasn't paying attention.. :P

Comment: @RobertAlvarez You can press check button and accept my answer instead . THX :)